# Using a dummy class for testing when required in a model

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mockery

I am looking for the best way to test a call in an API I have created.

My test is:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function it_can_return_a_block()
{
    $block = new Block();
    $block->type = "MyComp\MyOtherPackage\Widget";
    $block->save();

    $response = $this->call('GET', 'http://api.mysite.com/blocks?id=1');

    $response->assertExactJson([
        "id" => 1,
        "type" => "MyComp\MyOtherPackage\Widget",
        "component" => "widget",
        "name" => "My Widget"
    ]);
}
```

The Block model for this uses the `type` attribute to instantiate a `MyComp\MyOtherPackage\Widget` instance which is extended from another class: `MyComp\MyPackage\BlockDefintion` which is abstract:

```
public class Block
{
    ...

    private $definition;

    public function getDefinitionAttribute()
    {
        if(!$this->definition)
        {
            $this->definition = new $this->type;
        }

        return $this->definition;
    }

    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->definition->name;
    }

    public function getComponentAttribute()
    {
        return $this->definition->component;
    }

    ...
}
```

This test works fine if `MyComp\MyOtherPackage\Widget` is real and can be instantiated but these clases will be in a different package so I want to decouple the relationship in my test.

Is there a way to create some kind of dummy class to use here? I was thinking Mockery but not sure how I can use this in this instance

Comment: I think you should have a look at factories: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#writing-factories

Comment: `MyComp\MyOtherPackage\Widget` is not a model and so does not persist in the DB